# How to go into the hidden room in the Fire Sanctuary?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Right after you get the map in the Fire Sanctuary, a mogma tells you about a hidden room.

I can see the hidden room on my map, but How do I get to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you located it on the map, stand next to it. Place a bomb near the wall where the connection would be and stand back!

Since it's a "real" secret room, there is no crack in the wall indicating that it is breakable with a bomb, but it still is.